# question on expectation of random variable

Tags: statistics

If I have some discrete probability mass function for random variable $X$, like for example, 0 has probability 0.2, 1 has probability 0.3, 2 has probability 0.5, is the expected value $E(\sin(x)) = 0.2\sin(0) + 0.3\sin(1) + 0.5\sin(2)$?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is the expected value of $\sin(X)$. By the way $X$ is the random variable, not $x$, so we are calculating the expectation of another random variable $\sin(X)$ here.